# How to draw a tree in which each vertex contains some circles inside?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

I would like to recreate the following picture in Mathematica. I know how to draw a tree with GraphLayout. But I don't know how to create the shape of nodes as below. A bit hints about where to start will be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: `I know how to draw a tree with GraphLayout` -- include that code as a starting point, and the data you want to represent in numerical form. help us help you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
vertexShape[n_] := Graphics[{
   EdgeForm[Black],
   FaceForm[Lighter@Gray],
   Disk[{0, 0}],
   White,
   Disk[0.5 #, 0.2] & /@ CirclePoints[n]
   }]

shapes = Thread[Range[0, 11] -> Table[
     vertexShape@RandomInteger[4],
     12]];

SeedRandom[110]
g = TreeGraph[
  RandomInteger[#] \[UndirectedEdge] # + 1 & /@ Range[0, 10],
  EdgeStyle -> Black,
  VertexSize -> 0.5,
  VertexShape -> shapes
  ]
```

[image: Example]

Here's an example of how you can set internal nodes to blank and set the other ones according to some other rules:

```
shapes = Cases[
   Thread[Range[0, Length@VertexList[g] - 1] -> VertexOutDegree[g]],
   (x_ -> 1) :> (x -> vertexShape@RandomInteger[{1, 4}])
   ];
shapes = Prepend[shapes, _ -> vertexShape[0]];
```

Comment: Beautiful, and lightning fast! :-)

Comment: @MarcoB thanks :D

Comment: Your internal nodes with degree > 1 have inner circles. Shouldn't these be empty?

Comment: @flinty OP says he knows how to create the graph, he's just asking about how to create the vertex shapes, as far as I understand.

Comment: @flinty added an example of how to create the shape list too now though.

Answer (score 2):

```
(* generate a random tree *)
edges = Table[i <-> RandomInteger[{0, i - 1}], {i, 1, 20}]; 
(* random circles appear on edges with degree 1 only *)
circles = If[# == 1, RandomInteger[{1, 4}], 0] & /@ VertexDegree[Graph[edges]];
gencircles[{x_, y_}, name_] := 
 If[circles[[name + 1]] > 0, 
    Disk[{x, y} + 0.1*#, .05] & /@ CirclePoints[circles[[name + 1]]]
   , Nothing]
vsf[{x_, y_}, name_, {w_, h_}] := {Gray, Disk[{x, y}, .2], White, gencircles[{x, y}, name]}
Graph[edges,  VertexShapeFunction -> vsf]
```

[image: graph with dots]